# AS3 List with expanding sublists

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, list, button

Basically I have a list of states that scrolls through, and I want a list of towns to appear next to the state once the cursor is over it.

I tried making each state name a button, and going to the Over frame and adding the town list there, but the cursor picks up the towns when they're invisble, and all the town lists appear.

Is there a smarter way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not showing us any code, I still can help but it will be a little harder, what you need to do is something like this:

```
myStateButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, enableTowns);

function disableTowns($event:MouseEvent):void {
   $event.target.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, disableTowns);
   $event.target.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, enableTowns);
   myTownsSubmenu.mouseEnabled = false;
}

function enableTowns($event:MouseEvent):void {
   $event.target.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, enableTowns);
   $event.target.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, disableTowns);
   myTownsSubmenu.mouseEnabled = true;
}
```

What all this code does is first add a trigger on the button so when you move your cursor over it, this will execute the enableTowns function which is going to enable mouse focusing on the sub-buttons, when you move out this will disable the mouse focus on these buttons, it's important you nest this sprites or movieclips correctly.

Main Button -> Sub Buttons

Comment: You should avoid using the dollar sign in AS3. It's not going to throw any errors, but it also goes against common syntax.

Comment: Well actually people differs from coding standards for human readability, the dollar sign is require in the agency where I work for parameters inside methods written in AS3 so I guess I can't help it :)

Comment: That's fair enough. I can't remember where I read it, but I do believe Adobe discourages using any symbol other than an underscore or dash in object names. But it doesn't throw any errors, so I guess it's not entirely against the rules.